# Filtering content from Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So I'm coding a healthy social media app using Flutter and Firebase as my database.
I want to have a filter button where users can filter content based on the 'BoardType' field(in the picture)
Is there any way I can do this?
[Firebase screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE2Fk.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course, you can do so using filters like:

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('posts')
                    .where("BoardType", isEqualTo: "Book of the Month").get();
```

which is a future that returns the documents that match your request.